# routers function but cannot ping or remote admin

Tags: router, local-area-network

I have set up 3 cisco wireless routers as wireless access points.  Each has a static network ip and subnet/gateway identical to everything else on the network.  They also each have local ips that I can connect to by being wired straight in.

They work fine as wireless access points, providing internet and a network connection but I cannot ping or remote admin into any of them despite having enabled all of the options to do so, afaik.  Am I missing some step in configuring them?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your host interface to the WAP, is your host interface configured with the same IP address / subnet combo of the WAP interface?  I'm assuming that DHCP is not on the WAPs and that you will need to statically assign the addressing information on your host.
If IP routing is still enabled then it may act like a router instead of a switch.  The broadcast domain of your DHCP server on the network might not reach your host interface through the WAP.  That's my guess